# Fix language-related issues in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, language, input-languages

Every time I've installed Windows 7 with my location set as my actual location of Canada, it installs the OS to recognize my keyboard as a french keyboard.

It isn't, of course, but it still takes the input as if it is, and even if I change it and set it to recognize my keyboard as a US keyboard as it is, the next time I start up the system it's back to treating my keyboard as a french one. I've fixed this in the past, but the issue I'm faced with now is beyond that.

- The time, date, etc. are all in french format, to say 24 hour time, and the days of the week/name of month are complete gibberish to me.
- Most software I install installs and runs in French. Some software I use is fine as it offers in software settings to change the language, but a lot of it, specifically Deluge, which I use almost on the daily, offers no such setting. I've tried reinstalling, and in these installers setting the install language to English, but never fail, I open the software and it's in french.
- I've attempted to fix this issue and I don't know the results of my attempts yet, but my keyboard will ALWAYS register as a french keyboard when I start up my system. Even when and if I remove the french keyboard option from the input panel, its back to the french keyboard input setting next time I start up my system.

During the install process I never once selected that I wanted my system to do all of this. The BIOSes run in English, though I don't know if that'd have anything to do with these issues.

I've attempted everything that I can think of to fix these issues except reinstalling my operating system. *This is NOT an option.*

If anyone might have any idea on how to fix these problems, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Change your language preferences in Control Panel => Language (do not bother about displayed setting, this is particular one in *mine* Windows); change it to whatever fits your circumstances:

[image: Language preference]

2. Change system locale to English (Canada)

[image: Changing system locale]

at Control Panel => Region:

[image: CP=>Region]

3. Read [How can I change Deluge language?](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Troubleshooting#HowcanIchangeDelugelanguage) in Windows OS:

> There is a bug in the way GTK sets language on Windows but there are
>   several workarounds:
>
> ​Set a global `LANG` environment variable to the language you require,
>   e.g. `en`. Create a `cmd` file to set the `LANG` and open deluge. Copy
>   the following text into notepad:
>
> ```
> set lang=en
> start "" deluge.exe
> ```
>
> Save the file as `Deluge.cmd` in the same folder as `Deluge.exe`.
>   Create a shortcut to the `.cmd` file and use it to start Deluge.
>
> To force the use of English only, delete the following language files
>   from Deluge program folder:
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files\Deluge\deluge-1.3.x-py2.x.egg\deluge\i18n
> C:\Program Files\Deluge\share\locale
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Standard way to manage all that stuff:

Control Panel ->
Region and Language ->
Formats:
- here you could change date and time formats.

Control Panel ->
Region and Language ->
Keyboards and Languages ->
Change Keyboards:
- here you could add and/or remove input languages and set the default.